# How to convert aspell dictionary to simple list of words?

Tags: spell-check, dictionary, aspell

I want to get list of all words from aspell dictionary.
I downloaded aspell and aspell polish dictionary, then unziped it using:

```
preunzip pl.cwl
```

I got `pl.wl`:

```
...
hippie
hippies
hippiesowski/bXxYc
hippika/MNn
hippis/NOqsT
hippisiara/MnN
hippiska/mMN
hippisowski/bXxYc
...
```

but they appear with sufix like `/bXxYc` or `/MNn`. These suffixes are defined in `pl_affix.dat`, which looks like

```
...
SFX n Y 5
SFX n   a         0         [^ij]a
SFX n   ja        yj        [^aeijoóuy]ja
SFX n   a         0         [aeijoóuy]ja
SFX n   ia        ij        [^drt]ia
SFX n   ia        yj        [drt]ia
...
```

It is connected to the declination and conjugation. How can I add to the first list all forms (with all corresponding suffixes as defined in `.dat` file ) ?

BTW: I need this list to spell-checker `jazzy`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
aspell -d pl dump master | aspell -l pl expand > my.dict
```

**Edited** to match corrections in comment.

Comment: Nearly, I got what I wanted, but with english suffixes...
Example: "hippiesowski hippiesowskiens hippiesowskily"

Comment: Correct command is :
aspell -d pl dump master | aspell -l pl expand > my.dict

Now I got:

"hippiesowski niehippiesowski hippiesowskimi ..."

Comment: How do I extract all the properties of these words aswell?

Comment: How to convert a specific/single .rws file to text file?

Comment: Be aware that for some dictionaries - such as hu - the memory requirements for eliminating duplicates can be significant. As a workaround, limit `sort`'s memory usage to a value a gig or two below your system's generally available free memory, using its `-S` parameter. I use: `aspell -d ${lang} dump master | aspell -l ${lang} expand | tr -s '[:space:]' '\n' | LC_ALL=C sort -S28G -u > ${lang}.dict`

Answer (score 7):

For some languages, e.g. Italian, expanding is not enough and you will have to do some more processing to get a list of plain words.

This is the command I use to get a list of words in Italian (note that it will take some time to perform):

```
aspell -d it dump master | aspell -l it expand | sed "s/\w*'//g;s/ \+/\n/g" |
awk '{ print tolower($0) }' | uniq > wordlist.txt
```

### Breaking the pipeline

Aspell expansion:

- `aspell -d it dump master | aspell -l it expand > list1`

```
a
ab
abaco Quell'Abaco quell'Abaco quell'abaco Quest'Abaco quest'Abaco quest'abaco D'Abaco d'Abaco d'abaco Coll'Abaco coll'Abaco coll'abaco Sull'Abaco sull'Abaco sull'abaco Nell'Abaco nell'Abaco nell'abaco Dall'Abaco dall'Abaco dall'abaco Dell'Abaco dell'Abaco dell'abaco All'Abaco all'Abaco all'abaco L'Abaco l'Abaco l'abaco Bell'Abaco bell'Abaco bell'abaco Brav'Abaco brav'Abaco brav'abaco abachi
Abacuc
...
```

Remove any chars up to an apostrophe (included):

- `sed "s/\w*'//g" list1 > list2`

```
a
ab
abaco Abaco Abaco abaco Abaco Abaco abaco Abaco Abaco abaco Abaco Abaco abaco Abaco Abaco abaco Abaco Abaco abaco Abaco Abaco abaco Abaco Abaco abaco Abaco Abaco abaco Abaco Abaco abaco Abaco Abaco abaco Abaco Abaco abaco abachi
Abacuc
...
```

Break lines on space(s):

- `sed "s/ \+/\n/g" list2 > list3`

```
a
ab
abaco
Abaco
...
```

Lowercase the whole content in order to use `uniq` without sorting:

- `awk '{ print tolower($0) }' list3 > list4`

```
a
ab
abaco
abaco
...
```

Remove duplicates:

- `uniq list4 > list5`

```
a
ab
abaco
abachi
...
```